# Approximating a probability

Tags: probability-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A form of cumulative distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165282/a-form-of-cumulative-distribution)

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous independent RVs with $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as probability density functions, respectively. Assume that $E[Y]>E[X]$. Now, I have found numerically that the expression:
$$D=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min(f(x),g(x)) dx $$
which describes half the 'overlap area' of the two densities, is a rough approximation of:
$$ 
\Pr (Y \le X) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[f(x)\int _{-\infty}^{x}g(y)\,dy\right]\,dx 
$$

How can I *formally* show that the approximation holds for any two densities for which $E[Y]>E[X]$, and how can I quantify the strength of the approximation?

Comment: Are you sure about your finding? For example, if $f=g$, then $D=1$ and $P(Y\leqslant X)=\frac12$.

Comment: Where does the factor of $2$ come from in your expression for Pr($Y \le X$)?

Comment: Sorry, I now fixed the factor of 2.

Comment: It's not a duplicate since now I am asking about showing the approximation formally, and quantifying it...

Comment: @Dilip Thanks for the information. Asking again and again small variations of the same question seems to be all the rage these days... (About the condition $E(Y)>E(X)$, you are right but one can modify slightly $f$ to get some $g$ with $E(Y)>E(X)$, $P(Y\ge X)$ close to $\frac12$ and the former $D$ close to $1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Call $Q=\mathrm P(Y\leqslant X)$. Note that $2Q-1=2\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\int_{-\infty}^x (g-f)\cdot\mathrm dx$ and $2-4D=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R}|g-f|$.

Since $-(g-f)^-\leqslant g-f\leqslant(g-f)^+$ and $f\geqslant0$, $-2\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} (g-f)^-\leqslant 2Q-1\leqslant2\int_{\mathbb R} (g-f)^+$. Now, $\displaystyle2\int_{\mathbb R} (g-f)^+=2\int_{\mathbb R} (g-f)^-=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R}|g-f|$ , hence
$$
|2Q-1|\leqslant2(1-2D),
$$ 
in full generality (the hypothesis that $\mathrm E(Y)\gt\mathrm E(X)$ is not needed). Thus, $Q\to\frac12$ when $D\to\frac12$ (that is, in a sense, when $f$ and $g$ are close). By contrast, the inequality above is not informative when $D\leqslant\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks much, did. However, as you also note, your bound on |2Q-1| is really only meaningful when Q is large. In my application, I need to show that (and see how closely) D approximates Q when they are both very small (say, < 0.1)...

Comment: Unfortunately, when $D$ is small you really can't say anything about $Q$.  In fact you could have $D = 0$ if $f$ and $g$ are supported on disjoint sets (e.g. $f=0$ on the intervals $[n,n+1]$ where $n$ is odd and $g=0$ when $n$ is even), and $Q$ could be anywhere in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, but I assume (not explicitly stated) that f and g are continuous symmetric uni-modal distributions. I think in that case D approximates Q to some degree.